# How do I Connect to My Database Server Using MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mysql-workbench

I have a database in an Amazon Web Services instance that I'm trying to connect to using MySQL Workbench. However, I don't know what the database server is, all I know is the Public DNS and Public IP of my instance. I already set a Security Group to allow me to access my MySQL database using an external client, but how do I know what my database server is in an AWS EC2 instance?

Comment: U ssh putty to that puppy yet?

Comment: Right, as @AsConfused points out, you'll see a welcome message when you `ssh` into the instance, and that'll tell you what flavor of Linux you're running.

Comment: Yes, I use PuTTY to SSH into the AWS instance. When I use the mysql -uroot command, this is what I get: Your MySQL connection id is 35677
Server version: 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu). How do I get my Hostname, though, so I can connect to the Db server using Workbench? I assume my username is root and password is blank since I didn't set one.

Comment: Did u mess with conf file yet?

Comment: I guess it depends how you're connecting to the MySQL database. If you're connecting though an SSH tunnel, then the MySQL hostname would be `localhost`. If port 3306 is open and MySQL is configured to allow connections from your external IP, then the hostname would be the FQDN of the AWS instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys, I ended up finding out the answer myself. In MySQL Workbench, the default Connection Method is Standard (TCP/IP). I had to change this setting to Standard TCP over SSH. That was the key. After I realized that, it was easy to fill in the input fields with the appropriate values and I was able to connect to the database server on the AWS EC2 Instance.

Answer (score 0):

I reserve the right to be terribly wrong but

1) change my.conf (whatever your mysql conf file is called). 
And set `bind-address` to `0.0.0.0` as it is prob 127.0.0.1

2) stop/restart mysql daemon

3) nothing wrong with long public address. I often use elastic ip addresses which are free (sort of)

If bind-address is not changed you are screwed as per remote. It is a security default upon install